# How to remove numbers using twig in octobercms

Tags: php, twig, octobercms

I am trying to figure out how to remove numbers either from the left or from the right of a sting using twig I see twig has a method that removes white space rtrim or ltrim how do you remove say 1 first blog so that it reads first blog
I have tried {{ blog.post  | trim('1') }} but does nothing

Comment: You can use this, {{ blog.post | trim('1', 'left')}}

Answer (score 3):

After much reading and a little testing I have come up with this as rtrim or ltrim did not seem to work

```
{{ blog.post | trim('1234567890', 'left')}}
```